# How can I pack files inside Assets in Unity to reduce the quantity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, packing

I work with unity game projects with thousands of models and other resources inside the Assets folder. After a while, this becomes too slow and inconvenient, due to the constant refresh and meta files. Most of these files do not change constantly, so we can consider them static. Deactivating auto-refresh is ok, but there are still too many files.

**Is there a way to pack a bunch of files so Unity only handles one file for all of them inside the Assets folder?** I know there are packages, and budles, but to use them in the editor, you have to unpack them. Therefore, packages and budles wont' help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to your situation, you can first try organising them in different sub-folders. If one folder contains too many objects, it will cause lag for sure.

Instead of having thousands of prefab objects, you can also try export those 3D per scene as fbx in unity. Then, import this fbx as single file.

By doing this, your scene become single fbx instead.
For level or scene design, we used to combine everything or pack everything into one fbx object as possible. only keeping the necessary props as individual prefab.

ideally, you should also optimise the packed fbx in other 3D software. for example, removing duplicated faces, invisible faces..etc This workflow can cleanup the whole scene, and run smoother in low-end device or VR mobile headsets too.